# <EMBED> tag section 508 issue

Tags: html, embed, section508

I am working on fixing the section 508 compliance for `<EMBED>` tag. Below is the code

```
function playCaptcha() {
     var randomnumber;  
     randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000);
     //alert(randomnumber);
     document.getElementById("backsound").src="CaptchaAudio.aspx?num="+randomnumber;       

     document.getElementById("playAudio").innerHTML = '<EMBED src="CaptchaAudio.aspx?num="' + randomnumber + '" autostart="true"  hidden="true" id="Embed1" ALT="Captcha"></EMBED><NOEMBED><BGSOUND src="default2.aspx">Hello</NOEMBED>';
}
```

and the error is

EMBED tags must have a non-blank ALT tag. Add an ALT attribute with alternative content to the EMBED tag.
Guideline: WCAG1 A 1.1 Section 508 1194.22 (a) WCAG2 A H35

Though i have ALT tag the WCAG tool (sortSite) keeps complaining about it.. Any idea ?

Note : If i add the same EMBED code in the HTML section its not throwing the error, only with the JavaScript function

Comment: Is your tool crawling through the webpage before the javascript function has completed? If this is the case, the tool may be flagging the alt tag as empty before the javascript function has had a chance to populate the alt attribute.

Comment: The pedant in me says: since there is no such thing as an ALT tag, the error message is nonsense and you can easily ignore it.

Comment: I tried that sortSite tool on one of my own HTML documents and it gave me messages like "If you set any of the colors on the BODY tag you must set all of them" while I wasn't setting any of the colors on the BODY element. So really, you can take that tool with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions.

Comment: We are looking for a CAPTCHA framework that is section 508 compliant. That means it must have the audio read out feature for visually disabled people.

Do you know of a CAPTCHA framework other than reCaptcha that is 508 Compliant, apart from reCaptcha ( Google owned)?